# transform list of maps

Tags: arraylist, groovy

I have an  array like this:

```
def array = [[firstName:Nick], [lastName:Peter], [age:30]]
```

Now I want to transform it into:

```
def array = [firstName:Nick, lastName:Peter, age:30]
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding maps in groovy results in the same behaviour. By this the sum of the list of maps gives the same result:

```
def listOfMaps = [[firstName:'Nick'], [lastName:'Peter'], [age:30]]
assert [firstName:'Nick', lastName:'Peter', age:30] == listOfMaps.sum()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this...

```
def resultMap = [:]
def listOfMaps = [[firstName:'Nick'], [lastName:'Peter'], [age:30]]
listOfMaps.each {
    resultMap << it
}

assert resultMap == [firstName: 'Nick', lastName: 'Peter', age: 30]
```

Are you looking for something like that?

**EDIT**

To address a question in the comments below...

```
def resultMap = [:]
def listOfMaps = [[firstName:'Nick'], [lastName:'Peter'], [age:30]]
listOfMaps.each {
    resultMap << it
}

assert resultMap == [firstName: 'Nick', lastName: 'Peter', age: 30]

println "First Name: ${resultMap.firstName}"
println "Last Name: ${resultMap.lastName}"
println "Age: ${resultMap.age}"
```

The output is the following:

```
First Name: Nick
Last Name: Peter
Age: 30
```

Comment: Guys, BTW, does firstName:'Nick' become string? Because when I tried `res.firstName`, result is `null` instead of `Nick`, I need to get the key and value, any possible solution?

Comment: `resultMap.firstName` evaluates to 'Nick' in the example above as long as you evaluate `resultMap.firstName` after the call to `listOfMaps.each { ... } `.

Comment: Well, I know where the problem from. In my project, it doesn't show `Nick` inside the `quote`, it means that `[[firstName: Nick A], [lastName:Peter], [age:30]]`, then I get error when I run it.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
​def array = [[firstName:'Nick'], [lastName:'Peter'], [age:30]]​​​​​​
def res = [:];
array.each() { 
    res << it
}
print res​
```

Comment: FYI... the semicolon and the parens in your example are all superfluous.

Comment: Guys, BTW, does firstName:'Nick' become string? Because when I tried `res.firstName`, result is `null` instead of `Nick`, I need to get the key and value, any possible solution?

Comment: i'm getting res.firstName == 'Nick'. Can you post a snippet?

Comment: Well, when you have [firstName:'Nick'], with Nick in quote, it works. But in my project, it generates [firstName:Nick], I got error when I run it.

Comment: When you print a map in groovy, you will not see quotes around the string, i.e. [firstName:Nick]. What is Nick in this case? Could it be a Object or String that happens to be null?

Comment: @TranTam if you want to see (better) what the data is you can print the result of `inspect()`, which will give a representation of the data you are more likly to copy back into your code. e.g. `println array.inspect()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use many of the useful [Groovy Collections](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html) to achieve your result.

Here's a version using inject, initialising with an empty map, and then adding to it on each iteration of the list.

```
def s = listOfMaps.inject([:]) { acc, v -> acc += v; acc }
```

This works by adding to the map, then returning it as last value for next iteration.

Even shorter:

```
def s = listOfMaps.inject([:]) { acc, v -> acc + v }
```

This works because the value "acc + v" is also a map, and is returned for next iteration. There's no mutation here at all.

Inject is the functional equivalent of reduce in other languages such as clojure. I like doing it like this, because it creates the results in place, instead of creating an empty map and then mutating it.